# PHP results not getting MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I do not understand PHP and SQL. We are just barely scraping it at the end of the semester, and its frustrating me. I am trying to get my results page to show the correct info, but for the life of me, it won't grab anything. I clearly have something wrong and was wondering if I could get some help.

Initial page

(normal top of basic webpage here)

```
    <form id="ClubForm" action="ClubMembersResults.php" method="get">

    <?php            
        require_once ('dbtest.php');
        $query= "SELECT * FROM tblMembers ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, MiddleName;";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
            echo '<select id="memberid" name="memberid">';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['LastName'].'">'
                        .$row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']. '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        } else {
            echo "<p>No Members found!</p>";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Go" />
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

results page currently written as:

```
<?php
        $memid = 0;
        $memid = (int)$_GET['memberid'];
        if ($memid > 0) {

            require_once ('dbtest.php');
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE MemID = $memid;";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);`enter code here`
            if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
            echo "<p>Member ID: ".$row['MemID']."<br>";
            echo "Member Name: ".$row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['MiddleName']."<br>";
            echo "Member Joined: ".$row['MemDt']."<br>";
            echo "Member Status: ".$row['Status']."<br></p>";
            }else {
                echo "<p>Member not on file.</p>";
            }
            //table for inverntory
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<caption>Transaction History</caption>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Purchase Dt</th>";
            echo "<th>Trans Cd</th>";
            echo "<th>Trans Desc</th>";
            echo "<th>Trans Type</th>";
            echo "<th>Amount</th>";                
            echo "</tr>";
            $query2 = "SELECT p.Memid, p.PurchaseDt, p.TransCd, c.TransDesc, p.TransType, p.Amount
                       FROM tblpurchases p, tblcodes c
                       WHERE p.TransCd = c.TransCd AND p.MemId = 'member id'
                       ORDER BY p.MemId, p.PurchaseDt, p.TransCd
                       ";
            $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['PurchaseDt']."</td>;";
                echo "<td>".$row['TransCd']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['TransDesc']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['TransType']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Amount']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";                
        } else {
            echo '<p>No Member ID from form.</p>';
        }
?>
```

the results page should be showing tables with the info in the TH and TR/TD areas. Both those areas are coming from a separate SQL table, and teh the only similar field between the tblmembers and tblpurchases  is MemID.

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: `'member id'` in this line: `WHERE p.TransCd = c.TransCd AND p.MemId = 'member id'` should almost certainly be `$memid`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `join` in your `sql` request to show purchases by members.

```
  SELECT m.Memid, p.PurchaseDt, p.TransCd, 

                   FROM tblpurchases p join 
  tblmembers m on p.MemId=m.MemId
```

This is an example of a join

Comment: I'll be honest, we barely touched SQL, so I have no idea what you mean by a Join

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think we can edit that part of the code, as it was given to me directly from our Professor